# Checking if module has the right output on multilingual pages with simpletest_clone

Tags: testing, i18n-l10n

I'm trying with [simpletest_clone](http://drupal.org/project/simpletest_clone) to check if my modules have the right output depending on the language.

Now my problem is, that when I do the following Code:

```
$this->drupalGet('de');
// check the output

$this->drupalGet('fr');
// check the output again for the french version
```

Drupal then checks for `localhost/de/de` and `localhost/de/fr` (`de` is the default language) instead of `localhost/de` and `localhost/fr`

How can I change that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I would set the default langauge in code first instead.

```
// Get the list of languages
$languages = language_list();

// Set up the new language code
$new_lang_code = 'fr';

// Make sure the required language object is actually set
if (isset($languages[$new_lang_code])) {
  // Overwrite the global language object
  global $language;
  $language = $languages[$new_lang_code];
}
```

and then you just need to get the front page (and Drupal should add the prefix).

```
$this->drupalGet('<front>');
```

If `front` doesn't work you might need

```
$front_url = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
$this->drupalGet($front_url);
```